# Why was Bill Skarsgård cast for the role of Marquis?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-4

I saw John Wick 4 when it came out. I think the team did a great job, but I wonder why Bill Skarsgård was chosen for the main antagonist, Marquis. To me, he does not look and feel "dangerous". Dread and terror do not ooze from him. He does not feel like he would be the ultimate bad guy. He could maybe qualify as the right hand man of the main bad guy.

So my question is, **why was Bill Skarsgård chosen for the role of Marquis**, rather than someone with a more "dangerous" look and feel, a kind of person that would feel dominating and ooze fear, like Mark Dacascos (as Zero) or Riccardo Scamarcio (as Santino D'Antonio)?

Comment: The number of "good" characters who look a bit sinister combined with "evil" characters who look pretty is fairly large. Sirius Black and Dolores Umbridge from the Harry Potter universe are examples. My question is, why do you think the bad characters in a movie should look "dangerous"?

Comment: I've edited out some of the 'chatter' and made this a more focused question on why he was cast for the role. Hopefully that should result in some of these close votes being retracted.

Comment: Probably exactly because the makers didn't want that traditional or classically "dangerous" look and feel.

Comment: @Joachim - It turns out that the director would have let him play pretty much any role except Wick.

Comment: Wait.  Didn't he play Pennywise in _It_?  He looked pretty dangerous in that. lol

Answer (score 5):

Director Chad Stahelski was extremely keen to have Skarsgård in the film and essentially offered him carte blanche to pick any role that wasn't already cast. He anticipated that he'd go for one of the action roles, but cast him as the Maquis when Skarsgård said that that was his preferred choice.

> *"My former partner Dave Leitch, he used Bill on Atomic Blonde and during that process I got to meet him, and I really liked him, and I loved his work," says Stahelski. "Every time I [saw him in a film], I was just amazed about how he can morph his body and says a lot with non-verbal acting. I thought that was fascinating and that kind of fits with our world. **I called Bill, I said, 'Hey, I'm doing another John Wick, maybe there's a part in it for you, If we'll send you the rough script, and see if there's anything you like.'** I didn't say a word about which role. There was one I was thinking about, it was an older script with a character we no longer have, thinking, oh, he'll just go for that one. It was a bit of an action role.*
>
> ***He calls me back and he's like, 'I'd love to play the Marquis.'** I'm like, 'No, Bill, that's the bad guy. You don't want the bad guy.' He's like, 'No, no, that's the fun role! This is the delicious role!' **I'm like, 'Oh, right on!'"***
>
> <sub><sup>[Guns! Swords! Ice baths! How Keanu Reeves and Chad Stahelski created the action epic John Wick: Chapter 4](https://ew.com/movies/john-wick-4-creation-keanu-reeves-chad-stahelski/)</sup></sub>